# Can a key conflict occur using a 64-bit TKey, even if every value is unique?

Tags: .net, collections, hash

It seems everything hash-code related in .NET is 32-bits, yet most collection classes will permit you to use 64-bit primitives. That has me wondering, if I had a computer capable of running this block of code to completion:

```
Dictionary<ulong, object> test = new Dictionary<ulong, object>();
for (ulong x = ulong.MinValue; x <= ulong.MaxValue; x++)
    test.Add(x, null);
```

Would it succeed? Or would it throw a "key already exists" exception at some point during execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would it succeed?

Theoretically yes, practically no (see below).

> Or would it throw a "key already exists" exception at some point during execution?

Well, yes it will throw, but *not* because you have a key collision. It will throw because you run out of memory. There are 2^64 `ulong`s, they each take eight bytes, and so all the `ulong` s consume

8 * 2^64 = 2^67 = (2^10)^6.7 ~= (10^3)^(6.7) = 10^20 bytes ~= 100 exabytes.

Oops!

So I say "theoretically yes" because you won't have a key collision; that is, just because the keys are 64-bit `ulong`s but the hash codes are 32-bit does not mean that you will have a key collision. You will have *hash code* collisions, but *not* key collisions.

The keys are `ulong`. The implementation is that `Dictionary<ulong, object>` uses `Object.GetHashCode` to quickly test for membership in the `Dictionary<ulong, object>`. Given a `ulong x`, if `x.GetHashCode` is *not* equal to the hash code of some `ulong` saved in the dictionary, it can very quickly deduce that `x` is *not* in the dictionary. On the other hand, if `x.GetHashCode` *is* equal to the hash code of some `ulong` saved in the dictionary, it can very quickly compare `x` to all the `ulong`s in the dictionary that have the same hash code and return `true` if it finds `x` and `false` otherwise.

Comment: I think we all know it would run out of memory, lol. Great explanation of the Dictionary membership test! :)